# Vectorization in python -- multidimensional matrix by the range of parameters

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, multidimensional-array, iteration

I have 10 parameters, and their range is from 1 to 10.

I am trying to find a multidimensional matrix(array) for each parameter like this:

```
def function123(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,j,i,j):
    mat = np.array([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,j,i,j]).reshape(1,10)
    return mat * mat.T # 10 by 10  2D matrix

MAT = np.zeros([10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10]) #output matrix

for a in range(0,10):
    for b in range(0,10):
        for c in range(0,10):
            for d in range(0,10):
                for e in range(0,10):
                    for f in range(0,10):
                        for g in range(0,10):
                            for h in range(0,10):
                                for i in range(0,10):
                                    for j in range(0,10):
                                        MAT[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,j,i,j] = function123(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,j,i,j)
```

Is there any other clean way of solving this crazy for loops in python? 
I just do not want to see for loops. =[

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: The original computation is much more complicated, so I just simplified the calculating part into function123. =]

Comment: Maybe this? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndindex.html If the function is sufficiently complicated there may not be a sane way to vectorise it (e.g. if its doing a value lookup to some random Python object

Comment: Anyone who runs this code should be aware that `MAT`, as created by the line `MAT = np.zeros([10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10])`, will require 80 GB of memory.

Comment: If your function only works with scalar values you can't vectorize` the array creation.  You have to call it once for each array element, all 10**10 times.  Rethink what you are trying to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments should be respected, this code is very likely to have memory problems (which I experienced while trying as well). Probably there should be a better way to what you do and using those for loops are pretty easier than what I did, essentially. The way I treated this problem was as a nice challenge and the following code deals with it in a nice way.

```
def func123(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,i,j,k):
    return a*b*c*d*e*f*g*i*j*k

l = []
for i in range(10):
    arr = np.ones(10,dtype=int)
    arr[i] = 10
    l.append(np.arange(10).reshape(arr))

vec = np.vectorize(func123)
res = vec(l[0],l[1],l[2],l[3],l[4],l[5],l[6],l[7],l[8],l[9])
```

Here, I used the wonderful property of broadcasting for numpy arrays. You can change what function does and still store your array, if your memory permits.